# Argument type function(Game, string) is not assignable to parameter type PartialObserver<Game>|function(Game): void

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple Angular 2 service that I'm using to create a uni-directional flow of data. So the service exposes actions (`action$`) and the component can call `action$.next(game)`. The service subscribes to this action and re-emits to all listeners.

```
constructor() {
    this.action$ = new Subject();

    // Subscribe to actions
    this.action$.subscribe(this.handleAction);
}

  handleAction(game: Game, playerId: string) {}
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Argument type function(Game, string) is not assignable to parameter type PartialObserver<Game>|function(Game): void
```

If I remove the `playerId: string` then it works, but I don't understand where the `function(Game): void` definition is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't understand where the function(Game): void definition is coming from

A callback should only have one argument, which is the data that the observable will pass to you.

The error is telling what is allowed as an argument:

1. Either an instance of `PartialObserver<Game>`
2. Or a `function(Game)` (a function that takes a `Game` argument)

This is TypeScript syntax, when you want to say two types (use the `|`)

```
let something: number|string;        // something can be a number or string

function doit(id: number|string) {}  // you can pass a number or string
```

The signature for the `subscribe` is

```
subscribe(observer: PartialObserver<Game>|function(Game) => void)
```